# Redcarpet and JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

So, I'm trying to use JBuilder to return some fairly standard json, one of the fields being some markdown parsed into HTML by Redcarpet.

```
json.categories @all_categories do |category|
  json.extract! category, :name
  json.black_icon_url category.black_icon.url
  json.white_icon_url category.white_icon.url

  json.events category.events do |event|
    json.extract! event, :name, :short_description
    json.descripton event, @markdown.render(event.description)    # LOOK HERE!
    json.image_url event.image.url
    json.contacts [event.contact1, event.contact2] do |contact|
      json.extract! contact, :name, :phone, :facebook_username if contact
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that this piece of fairly simple code throws a `NoMethodError`.

```
Showing /../app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder where line #8 raised:

undefined method `<p>Speed is what defines us.</p>...
```

I'm a bit puzzled by this... it seems like this string is somehow turning into a method call?

Comment: derp, shouldn't that be `json.descripton @markdown.render(event.description)`?

Comment: Ah, =_= Sorry, I'm an idiot.